# wxWidgets wxMessageDialog works well in a secondary thread while a custom dialog doesn't

Tags: wxwidgets

**I am programming using C++ /CLI with wxWidgets on Windows 11.**

**I'm Also Using .NET threads**

---

When I create a `wxMessageDialog` in a secondary thread and run `->ShowModal()` , it works.

But when I create a custom dialog in a secondary thread, running `->ShowModal()` pops up a wxWidgets debug alert window :

[image]

I tried searching on the [wxWidgets forum](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=49267) for the same issue but couldn't find one. I found similar issues but none of them addresses my problem.

I also tried to surround `MyCustomDialog->ShowModal()` with calls to `wxMutexGuiEnter();` and `wxMutexGuiLeave();` , but that also didn't work.

I also learned about wxThread while scrolling through the forum but if wxMessageDialog works without me having to create a wxThread, I shouldn't have to create a wxThread myself.

---

I know I shouldn't be calling GUI methods from a secondary thread, but somehow `wxMessageDialog`'s `ShowModal()` doesnt have a problem with that.

I would like to know how wxMessageDialog works, and if I can implement the same thing with my custom dialog.

**Thank you.**

Comment: YOU SHOULD NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER EVER, NEVER EVER EVER USE OR ACCESS GUI CLASS IN A SECONDARY THREAD!!!!! No GUI class (in wxWidgets) is thread safe. You should always use all GUI classes from the main thread - a thread which initialize wxApp derived class.

Comment: Also it is pure coincidence that one GUI class works on you platform in you application. Also you are trying to implement something that you know will not work reliably? Is there a reason?

Comment: All of the predefined GUI classes work , not just one , I only mentioned one , Also my program does work ,

Comment: Will you answer the question instead of telling me not to use threads ?  >:(

Comment: please see above and below for the answer. BTW, I never said not to use threads - I said `don't access GUI classes inside secondary thread`. There is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a few words, **no there's no way to use a custom dialog from a secondary thread** with current implementation and in the foreseeable future.

Even though your current code works today using `wxMessageDialog`, there's no guarantee that it will continue to work tomorrow, or on different Windows version or on other OS.

Some more details:

- `wxMessageDialog` and a custom dialog are significantly different internally, even though they represent similar UI features.
- `wxMessageDialog` has *native implementation*, and you can find its `wxMessageDialog::ShowModal()` implementation in `src/msw/msgdlg.cpp`.
- A custom dialog will be assembled an run by wxWidgets code, even though the dialog itself and other components are native widgets. You can find `wxDialog::ShowModal()` in `src/msw/dialog.cpp`.

If you really want to pursue some experimental development (because it would still not be suited for anything else), and being on Win 11, you could try `wxRichMessageDialog`. It provides more features than `wxMessageDialog` and on Vista and later versions it has native implementation, which might go along with your "hack".

But again, using UI from secondary threads will lead to a dead end sooner or later.

Comment: Hmm what about if I start a thread and do nothing in the main thread. then can I do this ??

Comment: can you answer my question ??

Comment: I need threads, for a generic progress dialog, while im executing my function I need to update the progress dialog , but the progress dialog is blocked since i'm executing a function, thats why I need threads

Comment: Your app can use threads, but any calls to gui functions must be done in the main thread. If you want to update the gui based on work done in a secondary thread, you can either throw a [wxThreadEvent](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread_event.html) or use the [CallAfter](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a63c7351618fd77330d80a250b3719519) method to send the necessary info to the main thread.

Comment: Like @NewPagodi said. Do your work in secondary threads, and update the UI always in the main thread. The "main thread" (the one where you initialize wxWidgets) will always be the "GUI thread", no matter how less you do in it.

Comment: @NewPagodi wow , CallAfter() is amazing , I'm not using threads anymore :)